# Ambiente / Tecnologia para desenvolvimento aplicações Web em 3D

Tags: html5, aplicação-web, 3d, css-animations

Atualmente, muitas aplicações web utilizam-se de recursos 3D em suas aplicações. Um local onde encontrei alguns exemplos foi no [Chrome Experiments](https://www.chromeexperiments.com/). Um exemplo que instigou minha curiosidade foi esta [aplicação](https://jayweeks.com/medusae/).

Meu questionamento é:

Quais as são as tecnologias atuais para o desenvolvimento destes conteúdos? Quais são os ambientes de desenvolvimento para tais?

Comment: http://threejs.org/

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer o Medusae, foi utilizado HTML5 Canvas, JavaScript, Procedural GLSL entre outras técnicas.

O projeto inteiro do **Medusae** está no [GitHub](https://github.com/jpweeks/particulate-medusae).

As imagens do projeto você encontra no  [Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/jpweeks/sets/72157646887502644/)

Para saber mais sobre HTML5 Canvas visite o site [http://www.w3schools.com/HTML5 Canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp)